# Am I killing my future in software developing with my current job?

Tags: work-experience, work-life-balance, resignation

I'm a new, almost B.E graduate (Working on my thesis-work) and I'm working full time at the IT-department at my work. When I first started they say in the interview that I would be developing program and handle customers.

Now I'm not developing anything. I'm more of a "support specialist" regarding some system. Meaning that I've just learned the system and have more knowledge about them.

These system are old (We are talking 30 years old) so the code is nothing near what is up to current-code syntax.

So when I fix a problem within these system it's just general configuration. When I do tend to "develop", I generate code from a system the IT-department have developed that only works at this place and then add a small function do it and tada.. It's like calling yourself a cook but you are just warming food in the microwave.

I'm searching for new work since I'm not happy with the position that I'm currently in.
I've been to several work-interviews and in the end all of them comes back the same.

**"We want someone with more experience with this language/System etc"**

I can't get any experience with my current work with new languages/techniques and it feels like I'm losing the little I had during the school time.

**My question is am I killing my future within software developing by staying at a place like this?** Cause my plan is staying until I am done with my thesis-work but I'm unsure if other would want to hire me after, since I've been away from "new techniques" for at least one year.

Comment: If you're not getting the experience you need where you are, then go get it.  Yes, it's awful to work a full day and then go home and work.  It's more awful to work a job you don't enjoy your entire life because you weren't willing to push yourself.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From my personal experience, I approached the software development field the same way. I got a job as a 'support engineer' but I wasn't developing any code.
And because I was also a new graduate from university I had nothing to show for my experience except my degree. But what I do read from here and there is that people without a degree move into the field by working on a personal project.

Having Learned this, I wanted to do game development. So I started learning Unity and tried to build my own game (wasn't finished at the time I had my interview and got the job, but it didn't matter much to them because I showed I had learned something and was able to show it.)

So what I would suggest (personally speaking) is you find an open source project that interests you and contribute to that. Or, you could do what I did and find some platform/framework/game engine that interests you, have an idea and start building.

Comment: +1 when I was a web developer I felt as though I was going stale in my role, and after deciding to work on my own personal projects I found that i learned MUCH MORE than in the whole time working in that company.

Answer (score 5):

Yes and no.

No, because look at what else you're gaining/training: the skills and mindset needed for *maintenance*, which *all* software needs but few (ostensibly) want to do. I've landed more than one job, I believe, in part because I like maintenance work (that is, *really* getting to know one code base, as opposed to hopping around many as a short-term consultant would).

Yes, because obviously you'll find it hard to have interviews with "modern, interesting" companies that use ditto code. That you will have to nurture on your own time. If you can't (or won't) spend this extra time, then a job change is in place -- the sooner the better.

Either way -- jobs are ephemeral. **Do what makes *you* happy in the long term.**

PS. ...this from a guy who worked exclusively in Lotus Notes for 10 years at a rather traditional company, but nevertheless is now working in a rather neat and fast-moving Java/PHP shop. It's possible!

Answer (score 1):

From the responses you mention, it seems like you might be hoping to get a non-entry level position as a developer.

Until you get the actual experience required, you just have to realise that you will have to start at the bottom of the ladder, and not try and jump ahead. This might even involve a slight drop in pay, I'm afraid.